# LWW 40 SOT-23 transistor replacement for PC Motherboard

Tags: transistors, identification, surface-mount

I want to find a replacement for SOT-23 transistor. The top marking of the transistor is LWW 40. I found the same part online with marking LWW 81, but I don't know if it is the right part. It would be much appreciated if someone could help me find a replacement for this transistor.

[image: photo of component]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome! If you zoom out the picture a bit, it may be possible to figure out the pinout.

From this sketchy source, https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001106274466.html, it's probably a 2N7002 N-channel MOSFET.

Less sketchy source found by Spehro: https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/2N7002P.pdf
[image]

"40" is probably date code or possibly assembly line.

Comment: +1 Appears to be a Nexperia 2N7002P (or a compatible part with similar markings). LW is the part code, W is the manufacturing site, the rest probably a date code.